# selecting columns by colSums and filtering by rowSums in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table)
a <- mtcars
setDT(a)
b <- a[,colSums(.SD)>500,.SDcols=setdiff(names(a),c("vs","am"))]
```

In this contrived example, I´d like to select the columns fulfilling the `colSums` condition, without using the `vs` and `am` columns. The code above just results in a logical vector of the correct columns, but without actually selecting the desired entire columns into a new dt. Moreover, the `setdiff` solution to `.SDcols` seems quite terse and verbose. Is there a more efficient/succint syntax to do this - I tried using .SDcols=-c("vs","am") to no help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `.SD` to select to columns based on the logical vector

```
library(data.table)
a[, .SD[, colSums(.SD)>500, with = FALSE],.SDcols=setdiff(names(a),c("vs","am"))]
```

---

If we wanted to do `rowSums`, just use that as index

```
d <- a[, .SD[rowSums(.SD)>300],.SDcols=-c(8,9)]
```

Or with `Reduce`

```
 a[, .SD[Reduce(`+`, .SD) > 300], .SDcols = -c(8, 9)]
```

If we need to get all the columns, use `.I` instead of `.SD`

```
a[a[, .I[Reduce(`+`, .SD) > 300], .SDcols = -c(8, 9)]]
```

Comment: Very good. And if I want to filter by rowSums? `d <-a[.SD[rowSums(.SD)>300,with=F],.SDcols=-c(8,9)]` throws an error

Comment: Guess there must be 10min before the upvote can be given. Tried a couple of minutes ago while working on rowSums

Comment: @Misha  can you check my upddate

Comment: thx a million. Somehow the `j` position for rowSums eludes me. Thought it should have been in `i`.

Comment: @Misha By default,  in  data.table, the index is taken for `i` (opposite to data.frame, where it is `j`)

Comment: a final question-- in the `rowSums` instance, if I´d like to return all columns from `a`, not just the `.SDcols` - how would I go about that in a succint manner?

Comment: @Misha if it is all columns, you don't need to specify `.SDcols`

Comment: But I´d like the condition for the row filtering to be based on only the columns in .SDcols, but like all columns to be returned (not just .SDcols).

Comment: Nifty-but quite complicated syntax

Comment: @Misha you could remove the `.I`  and it should work as well.  I was thinking that if there is a group by statement, the `.I` would be more relevant